# null pointer exception at org.hibernate.tuple.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am using hibernate 3.2 with struts 1.2 framework 
here is the details of versions hibenate3.2,asm-2.2.3,cglib-2.1.3 
I got this exception when i m trying to load the object

I am using this code to load the object

```
public Currentprofile findById(java.lang.String id) {
    log.debug("getting Currentprofile instance with id: " + id);
    try {
        Currentprofile instance = (Currentprofile) getSession().get(
            "com.hibermappings.Currentprofile", id);
        return instance;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("get failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

My hbm file is this

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.hibermappings.Currentprofile" table="currentprofile" catalog="naukrionphone">
    <id name="jobseekerId" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="jobseekerId" length="50" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>

    <one-to-one name="referenceDb" lazy="proxy" class="com.hibermappings.ReferenceDb" cascade="all" constrained="false" /> 
    <one-to-one name="registration" lazy="proxy" class="com.hibermappings.Registration" cascade="all" constrained="false" /> 
    <one-to-one name="jobseekerpackagedetails" lazy="proxy" class="com.hibermappings.Jobseekerpackagedetails" cascade="all" constrained="false" /> 

    <property name="keyWords" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="keyWords" length="5000" />
    </property>
    <property name="totalExp" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="totalExp" length="100" />
    </property>
    <property name="hqualification" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="hQualification" length="100" />
    </property>
    <property name="preferedLocation" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="preferedLocation" length="100" />
    </property>
    <property name="functionalArea" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="functionalArea" length="1000" />
    </property>
    <property name="expSalary" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="expSalary" length="100" />
    </property>
    <property name="designation" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="designation" length="100" />
    </property>
    <property name="resumeTitle" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="resumeTitle" length="500" />
    </property>
    <property name="profileDetails" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="profileDetails" length="65535" />
    </property>
    <property name="requiredProfile" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="requiredProfile" length="65535" />
    </property>
    <property name="activatedOn" type="java.util.Date">
        <column name="activatedOn" length="0" />
    </property>

    <set name="resumes" inverse="true" cascade="save-update">
        <key>
            <column name="jobseekerId" length="50" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.hibermappings.Resume" />
    </set>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

the same code runs well when I m using in a simple java class within main method ..

full stack trace of exception is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hibernate.tuple.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:372)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3121)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:232)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:173)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:87)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:862)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:781)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:774)
 at com.DAOs.CurrentprofileDAO.getLoad(CurrentprofileDAO.java:71)
 at com.action.JobSekeerManage.viewProfile(JobSekeerManage.java:447)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
 at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:270)
 at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:187)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
 at com.filter.HibernateFilter.doFilter(HibernateFilter.java:24)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:825)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:731)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:526)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Error::null
```

In my Log file I got this type of exception..

```
INFO - building session factory
WARN - No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml found in the classpath: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%205.5/webapps/NewNaukriOnPhone/WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-1.1.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
ERROR - CGLIB Enhancement failed: com.hibermappings.ReferenceDb
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visit(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
 at net.sf.cglib.core.ClassEmitter.begin_class(ClassEmitter.java:77)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:173)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
 at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.(Enhancer.java:69)
 at org.hibernate.proxy.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:116)
 at org.hibernate.proxy.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:41)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:161)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.AbstractEntityTuplizer.(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:131)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoEntityTuplizer.(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.TuplizerLookup.create(TuplizerLookup.java:64)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.EntityMetamodel.(EntityMetamodel.java:257)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.(AbstractEntityPersister.java:412)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:108)
 at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:216)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1176)
 at com.HibernateSessionFactory.rebuildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:66)
 at com.HibernateSessionFactory.getSession(HibernateSessionFactory.java:49)
 at com.DAOs.BaseHibernateDAO.getSession(BaseHibernateDAO.java:15)
 at com.DAOs.PostedprofileDAO.findByProperty(PostedprofileDAO.java:84)
 at com.admin.SendProfileAction.viewProfile(SendProfileAction.java:309)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
 at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:270)
 at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:187)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
 at com.filter.HibernateFilter.doFilter(HibernateFilter.java:24)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:825)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:731)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:526)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
WARN - could not create proxy factory for:com.hibermappings.ReferenceDb
org.hibernate.HibernateException: CGLIB Enhancement failed: com.hibermappings.ReferenceDb
 at org.hibernate.proxy.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:132)
 at org.hibernate.proxy.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:41)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:161)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.AbstractEntityTuplizer.(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:131)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoEntityTuplizer.(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.TuplizerLookup.create(TuplizerLookup.java:64)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.EntityMetamodel.(EntityMetamodel.java:257)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.(AbstractEntityPersister.java:412)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:108)
 at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:216)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1176)
 at com.HibernateSessionFactory.rebuildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:66)
 at com.HibernateSessionFactory.getSession(HibernateSessionFactory.java:49)
 at com.DAOs.BaseHibernateDAO.getSession(BaseHibernateDAO.java:15)
 at com.DAOs.PostedprofileDAO.findByProperty(PostedprofileDAO.java:84)
 at com.admin.SendProfileAction.viewProfile(SendProfileAction.java:309)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
 at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:270)
 at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:187)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
 at com.filter.HibernateFilter.doFilter(HibernateFilter.java:24)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:825)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:731)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:526)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visit(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
 at net.sf.cglib.core.ClassEmitter.begin_class(ClassEmitter.java:77)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:173)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
 at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
 at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.(Enhancer.java:69)
 at org.hibernate.proxy.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:116)
 ... 45 more
ERROR - CGLIB Enhancement failed: com.hibermappings.Companyprofile
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
 at org.hibernate.proxy.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:116)
 at org.hibernate.proxy.CGLIBProxyFactory.postInstantiate(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:41)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:161)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.AbstractEntityTuplizer.(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:131)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoEntityTuplizer.(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.TuplizerLookup.create(TuplizerLookup.java:64)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.EntityMetamodel.(EntityMetamodel.java:257)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.(AbstractEntityPersister.java:412)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:108)
 at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:216)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1176)
 at com.HibernateSessionFactory.rebuildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:66)
 at com.HibernateSessionFactory.getSession(HibernateSessionFactory.java:49)
 at com.DAOs.BaseHibernateDAO.getSession(BaseHibernateDAO.java:15)
 at com.DAOs.PostedprofileDAO.findByProperty(PostedprofileDAO.java:84)
 at com.admin.SendProfileAction.viewProfile(SendProfileAction.java:309)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
 at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:270)
 at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:187)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
 at com.filter.HibernateFilter.doFilter(HibernateFilter.java:24)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:825)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:731)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:526)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.ru
```

here is the details of versions hibenate3.2,asm-2.2.3,cglib-2.1.3

Comment: any hibenate professional........?

Comment: Are you sure the stacktrace corresponds to the code you are showing?

Comment: definitly.....it corresponds to the code that are showing

Comment: Weird, I don't see calls to `findById` and `SessionImpl.get`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this works outside the web application, check that your mapping file is well packaged and found when the `SessionFactory` is created when running in container.

**Update:** You have a wrong version of **ASM** on the classpath (at least, not the one expected by CGLIB). What versions of Hibernate, ASM and CGLIB are using exactly? Are you using the JARs that ship with Hibernate? See if the solution given in [this thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2373390) works for you. Another option would be to switch from CGLIB to Javassist.

**Update:** You need **asm-1.5.3.jar** with **cglib-2.1.3.jar** (or to replace both with **cglib-nodep-2.1.3.jar**, see [HHH-2222](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2222)). **Use the JARs of Hibernate distribution.**

Comment: my mapping file is well packaged is there any problems in creating proxy..?

Comment: what could be the problem..?please provide me some links from where i can get the details...

Comment: @saurabh It's impossible for me to answer this question with the current level of detail. Can you confirm the mapping is found when the SessionFactory is created (activate logging and check application startup logs).

Comment: here is the details of versions hibenate3.2,asm-2.2.3,cglib-2.1.3

Comment: @saurabh Thanks. BTW, the common way of recognizing a good answer is upvoting it ;) Also check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting